# Bucle que permita hacer una función dentro de una tabla

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

Estoy haciendo un juego de ajedrez y estoy haciendo la función que me permita identificar las casillas en las cuales puede moverse la pieza, en este caso el alfil.

He hecho un bucle para darle color a esas casillas donde podría moverse el alfil, digamos que obtengo la posición de fila y columna del alfil y logro hacer que desde su posición las demás filas y celdas (una fila más y una columna más) cambien de color en forma diagonal hacia abajo.

Hasta aquí todo bien. Ahora he intentado de distintas formas que también cambie el color de las celdas en diagonal hacia abajo-izquierda, arriba-derecha y arriba-izquierda y no logro conseguirlo.

En los intentos más cercanos creo otras variables distintas para que sumen y resten dentro del bucle pero terminan restándole posibles casillas.

¿Cómo se soluciona esto?

```js
document.write("<table id='mitabla' border='1'  width='900px' heigth='1100px'>")

for (i=1; i<9; i++) {
  fila = i;
  document.write("<tr>")

  for (j=1; j<9; j++) {
    columna = j;
    if (i%2==0 && j%2==0) {
      document.write("<td ondrop='drop(event)' ondragover='allowDrop(event)' width='100px' height='110px' bgColor='white'></td>")

    } else if (i%2!=0 && j%2!=0) {
      document.write("<td ondrop='drop(event)' ondragover='allowDrop(event)' width='100px' height='110px' bgColor='white'></td>")
    } else if (i%2==0 && j%2!=0) {
      document.write("<td id='black-Par-Impar' width='100px' height='110px' bgColor='black'></td>")
    } else if (i%2!=0 && j%2==0) {
      document.write("<td id='black-Impar-Par' width='100px' height='110px' bgColor='black'></td>")
    }
  }
  document.write("</tr>")
}

numeracionColumna = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
document.write(numeracionColumna.length);

numeracionColumna[0].innerHTML = "<img onmouseover='jugada(this.id)' onclick='posicionPieza(this.id)' mouseover='mouseOver()' mouseout='mouseOut()' id='alfilnegro1' draggable='true' ondragstart='drag(event)' src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/44/44903.png'>";

alfilnegro1 = document.getElementById("alfilnegro1")

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}
function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}
function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById("alfilnegro1"));
}

function posicionPieza(nombre) {

  for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<8; j++) {
      if (document.getElementById("mitabla").rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML == '<img onmouseover="jugada(this.id)" onclick="posicionPieza(this.id)" mouseover="mouseOver()" mouseout="mouseOut()" id="alfilnegro1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/44/44903.png">') {
        //alert("hay un alfil en la fila "+i+" columna "+j)

        var posicionCeldaAlfil = fila * 8 + columna
        var fila = i
        var columna = j

        for (m=0; m<9; m++) {
          i++
          j++

          document.getElementById("mitabla").rows[i].cells[j].bgColor = "blue"
          fila--
          columna--
          document.getElementById("mitabla").rows[fila].cells[columna].bgColor = "red"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

document.write("</table>")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que solo recorres una línea, pero esa línea se pasa del array y no te deja hacer los siguientes `for`, por lo que debes controlar que no sobrepase los límites del array, y a continuación hacer un `for` para cada dirección:

```
function posicionPieza(nombre){

  for(i=0;i<8;i++){
    for(j=0;j<8;j++){
      if(document.getElementById("mitabla").rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML=='<img onmouseover="jugada(this.id)" onclick="posicionPieza(this.id)" mouseover="mouseOver()" mouseout="mouseOut()" id="alfilnegro1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" src="probebis.jpg">'){
        //alert("hay un alfil en la fila "+i+" columna "+j)

        var posicionCeldaAlfil= fila*8+columna;
        var fila=i;
        var columna=j;
        document.getElementById("mitabla").rows[fila].cells[columna].bgColor="red";

        for(m=0;m<9;m++){
          if((i<=6)&&(j<=6)){/*controlamos que no sobrepase el array*/
            /*derecha abajo*/
            i++;
            j++; 
            document.getElementById("mitabla").rows[i].cells[j].bgColor="blue";
          }else{m=9;}/*si sobrepasa el array, con este else salimos del bucle*/
        }
        /*Volvemos a colocar la posicion inicial de la figura*/
        i=fila;
        j=columna;
        for(m=0;m<9;m++){
          if((i>=1)&&(j<=6)){/*controlamos que no sobrepase el array*/
            /*derecha arriba*/
            i--;
            j++; 
            document.getElementById("mitabla").rows[i].cells[j].bgColor="blue";
          }else{m=9;}/*si sobrepasa el array, con este else salimos del bucle*/
        }
        /*Volvemos a colocar la posicion inicial de la figura*/
        i=fila;
        j=columna;
        for(m=0;m<9;m++){
          if((i<=6)&&(j>=1)){/*controlamos que no sobrepase el array*/
            /*izquierda abajo*/
            i++;
            j--; 
            document.getElementById("mitabla").rows[i].cells[j].bgColor="blue";
          }else{m=9;}/*si sobrepasa el array, con este else salimos del bucle*/
        }
        /*Volvemos a colocar la posicion inicial de la figura*/
        i=fila;
        j=columna;

        for(m=0;m<9;m++){
          if((i>=1)&&(j>=1)){/*controlamos que no sobrepase el array*/
            /*izquierda arriba*/
            i--;
            j--; 
            document.getElementById("mitabla").rows[i].cells[j].bgColor="blue";
          }else{m=9;}/*si sobrepasa el array, con este else salimos del bucle*/
        }
        /*una vez terminados todos los bucles, igualamos los bucles pricipales a 8 para que salga de ellos*/
        i=8;
        j=8;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! Ya lo he probado y funciona, solo la función de arriba izquierda tiene un fallo cuando se posiciona en la fila 2 columna 6, lo revisare para ver como lo resuelvo.

Comment: Es cierto, he tenido un pequeño error, el error es, que en el "if" de comparación he puesto 7 en lugar de 6, y sobrepasa el array lo he vuelto a editar, y ahora no debe dar errores.

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorge!! Con este ejercicio he aprendido a frenar los bucles para poder ejecutar otros, muchas gracias de verdad!!

Comment: Genial! para eso estamos jeje, sigue así estás haciendo un gran trabajo!!

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorge! Tengo un mes aprendiendo JavaScript, HTML y CSS. Espero poder seguir aprendiendo.